# How can I use xmlstarlet to query a tag for two attribute values?

Tags: xmlstarlet

Example:-
`<item href="cover.jpeg" id="cover" media-type="image/jpeg"/>`

I'd like to select @id="cover" and media-type="image/*" and retrieve @href.

My current "solution" seems to be:-
`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//_:item[@id='$opf_cover_name']" -v @href -o '|' -v @media-type -n file.xml`, followed by some extremely messy splitting around the '|' character of the output.

```
Does xmlstarlet have a substring function?
Version = 1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.4, linked with 20904
compiled against libxslt 1.1.29, linked with 10132
```

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
the_id='cover'
the_mediatype_prefix='image/'

xmlstarlet sel -t \
    --var queryid="'$the_id'" \
    --var typeprefix="'$the_mediatype_prefix'" \
    -v '//item[@id = $queryid and starts-with(@media-type, $typeprefix)]/@href' \
    -nl file.xml
```

This queries the XML file using two shell variables.  The `the_id` variable contains the `id` attribute value that we are filtering with, while `the_mediatype_prefix` contains the string that the `media-type` attribute has to start with.

We create two internal variables for `xmlstarlet` using the tool's `--var` option.  The values need to be encoded values, which is why I insert single quotes around them (this is a bit of a hack, ideally they should be properly encoded XPath strings, but it's marginally better than injecting shell variables directly into the expression).

The XPath expression select the `href` attribute of each `item` node that has the matching `id` and `media-type`.

---

Using `xq` ([an XML parser wrapper](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/)  around `jq`, the JSON parser) instead:

```bsh
the_id='cover'
the_mediatype_prefix='image/'

xq -r \
    --arg queryid "$the_id" \
    --arg typeprefix "$the_mediatype_prefix" '
    .. | .item? |
    select(
        ."@id" == $queryid and
        (."@media-type" | startswith($typeprefix))
    )."@href"' file.xml
```

This is more or less identical to the `xmlstarlet` code, apart from using a `jq` expression instead of a XPath query.  Here, the utility takes care of encoding your shell variables properly, even if they contain wonky values like quotes etc. (the shell variable values in the `xmlstarlet` example would need to be encoded manually if they contain illegal character sequences).

Comment: +1 I'd not previously come across the `--var` parameters; thank you for teaching me that

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple conditions:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//item[@id='cover'][starts-with(@media-type,'image/')]" -v '@href' -nl file.xml
```

Comment: @JeremyBoden your question said you wanted to match against a fixed `id` and `media-type`. If you wanted to match against a variable you'd pop a variable in the expression, ensuring that the variable value was suitable mangled so as not to contain an unescaped single quote

Comment: My problem was a variable `id` (which was OK) and a `media-type` which is a mime-type such as 'image/jpeg' or 'image/png' etc. I wasn't aware how to handle an `and` condition or a 'starts-with' function. Your solution is short , and it works too! Thanks.